# Do you any have access to Computer Science Review Elsevier Journal MS word Template?

Tags: publications, phd, research-process, computer-science

I'm in the process of submitting a paper to the Computer Science Review Elsevier Journal. I've gone through their "Guide for Authors," but I'm finding it a bit challenging to discern the specific font, size, and other formatting details. Would anyone happen to have experience with this journal and perhaps possess a Microsoft Word template tailored for their submissions? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: For papers in computer science, I would really recommend you use LaTeX. [Here is information on LaTeX for Elsevier journals.](https://beta.elsevier.com/researcher/author/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions?trial=true)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest to follow @Stephan Kolassa advice and use Latex.

You can find the [Latex instruction linked in comment here](https://www.elsevier.com/researcher/author/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions).

According to their FAQ as of the 16th of November [linked here](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5955/supporthub/publishing/role/author/):

> Most journals accept a PDF of your manuscript at initial submission and require you to submit your manuscript with source files at a later stage. However, some journals require a manuscript to be submitted in a specific template file. In these cases, the template is probably in LaTeX and in exceptional cases in CRC.

Additionally, the FAQ also gives the following information:

> If a journal requires you to use a certain template for submission, you can find this in the journal's Guide for Authors. Consult your Guide for Authors from the journal homepage. To go to your journal's homepage, search for the journal using the search box under 'Find by journal title' in the journal author's page.

Going to the Guide for Authors for Computer Science Review Elsevier Journal [which you can find ehre](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/computer-science-review/publish/guide-for-authors), I can find the following information (emphasis mine):

> Our online submission system guides you stepwise through the process of entering your article details and uploading your files. The system converts your article files to a single PDF file used in the peer-review process. **Editable files (e.g., Word, LaTeX) are required to typeset your article for final publication.** All correspondence, including notification of the Editor's decision and requests for revision, is sent by e-mail.

I also find the following quote a bit below in the "Use of word processing software" paragraph:

> Keep the layout of the text as simple as possible. Most formatting codes will be removed and replaced on processing the article. In particular, do not use the word processor's options to justify text or to hyphenate words. However, do use bold face, italics, subscripts, superscripts etc.

From those quotes, it appears the manuscript is gonna go through typesetting, and thus those formatting details you are wondering about are not important, and are only relevant to your first submission, if you submit only a PDF. In later stages, you will be asked to submit source files and format won't matter anymore.

The guide for authors also suggest using Latex:

> You are recommended to use the Elsevier article class [elsarticle.cls](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle) to prepare your manuscript and [BibTeX](http://www.bibtex.org/) to generate your bibliography.
> Our [LaTeX site](https://www.elsevier.com/researcher/author/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions) has detailed submission instructions, templates and other information.